# Prevent Data backup with iCloud and itunes

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I am developing an iOS application. the user can download books, the size of books ar > 200 Mo. To respect the apple storage guidelines, we are doing like this :

```
 + (NSString *)booksStoragePath
    {

        NSArray *path = [NSArray array];
        NSString *os5 = @"5.0";
        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

        if ([currSysVer compare:os5 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending) //5.0.1 and above
        {        
            path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

        }
        else // IOS 5
        {
            path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        }

       NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory
        NSString *storagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Books"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:storagePath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:storagePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

NSUrl *url = [NSUrl urlWithString:storagePath];
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:url];

        return storagePath;
    }
```

And to not backup the "Books" directory, i am doing like this :

```
#pragma mark --
#pragma mark Data Backup
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    NSString *os5 = @"5.0.1";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];


    if ([currSysVer compare:os5 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame) //5.0.1
    {    
        const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

        const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
        return result == 0;

    }
    else{
        if ([currSysVer compare:os5 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending) {



            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                          forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
            if(!success){
                NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
            }
            return success;
        }
    }

    return nil;

}
```

The problem is i am seeing the folder "Books" in iTunes connect an i can download it, and all the content of the books are there !!!!!

How i can forbid that the directory "Books" and it's content does not synchronize with iCloud ans does not appear in the iTunes ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why do you have the iOS version determining which directory your file is going into? If it goes into the cache directory, it should not show up in iTunes, otherwise, it should.

Comment: i want to no show it if i put it in Documents directory. I can not put the "Books" directory in caches because the system can purge the caches